# Cakephp architexture - which plugins do you actually use

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

There are components that can be used for each Cakephp project, like auth-management plugin etc.

What is your initial archtexture - common to all cakephp projects

Which plugins do you actually use usually, and do you use them all together or some of these plugins must exclude one another

if so, which plugins do you use for:

Seo-plugin
Auth-management plugin  ( which auth management plugin do you use ?)
Forum plugin
Comments plugin
Blog plugin
Shopping cart plugin
Clear-cache plugin
Facebook and Twitter plugins 
Netbeans plugin
Search plugin 
Github plugin

Do you integrate it usually with some CMS plugin , Any CMS like Wildflower - to keep it all together,

are there any other plugins that you use from project to project

Comment: What the hack is an "architexture"? If you mean architecture, I drop in plugins for which need arises in on a particular project. You can only shoot yourself in the foot and waste time by thinking which plugins you want to pull in when you do not need them in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

By the nature of the type of website I build, I usually include Auth and possibly ACL from the outset. Probably i28n too - from an early age I was encouraged not to put text in views, but to use system message calls.

I don't use plugins - I've never had one that worked for less work than I could build one.

I cut and paste my way from one project to another.

Comment: *i28n* stands for… "insupercalifragilisticexpation"? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've actually started to make a modular, scalable base application for Cake 1.3.

Essentially, you have a plugin (which I'm calling Icing) that contains any custom classes, components, helpers or libs I might use in all areas of the project (which can be accessed by other plugins too). For example, I have a location based YAML config class.

Then, I have a 'core' plugin that gives an admin area which has user management and role-based ACL management.

Then, I create new plugins for each area of functionality such as blog, page management etc.

My layouts, CSS, Javascript and images plus anything completely unique to a project will reside in Cake's normal folder structures. You end up with the ability to copy and paste plugin folders in which will instantly give you access to new functionality.

Like the previous answers, Auth component and a few helpers normally make it into the app_controller.php

I'm sorry to say that most of my plugins are things I've written though.

DebugKit by Mark Story is fantastic though for analysing what's going on.